# How to migrate to specific version using Migrator.NET

Tags: sql-server, msbuild, migratordotnet

Is there any way to rollback to a specific version using Migrator.NET?

I'm running migrations on a SQL Server 2005 database using MSBuild;

> "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\MSBuild.exe"
>   /target:UpdateDb
>   /property:MigrationConnectionString="ConnectionString"
>   "D:\Projects\My.Migrations.csproj"

Answer (score 2):

I found my target section (in My.Migrations.csproj) having a property named "To".

```
  <Target Name="UpdateDb">
    <CreateProperty Condition="'$(To)'==''" value="-1">
      <Output PropertyName="To" TaskParameter="Value">
      </Output>
    </CreateProperty>
    <Migrate Provider="SqlServer" Connectionstring="$(MigrationConnectionString)" Migrations="$(OutputPath)$(AssemblyName).dll" To="$(To)" />
  </Target>
```

So just by adding **/p:To=5** (where 5 is the version number found in SchemaInfo) to the MSBuild run mentioned in the question, I was able to rollback my DB. Hope this helps someone.